# Mudar backgroud de uma class em evento de outra

Tags: html, css

Tenho o seguinte código:

```css
.line-item:hover td {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.item-text:focus + .line-item td {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<tr class="line-item">
  <td>L1C1</td>
  <td>L1C2</td>
  <td><input class="item-text" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="line-item">
  <td>L2C1</td>
  <td>L2C2</td>
  <td><input class="item-text" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

O objetivo é deixar a linha em que o `text` foi focado vermelha.

Resultado obtido: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Resultado desejado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Ao passar o mouse sobre qualquer elemento perceba que a linha fica
>   amarela. Ao clicar no text eu gostaria que a linha ficasse vermelha.

Usando JavaScript ficaria assim:

```js
$(".item-text").focusin(function(){
  $(this).closest(".line-item").css("background-color", "red");
}).focusout(function(){
 $(this).closest(".line-item").css("background-color", "transparent");
});
```

```css
.line-item:hover td {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr class="line-item">
  <td>L1C1</td>
  <td>L1C2</td>
  <td><input class="item-text" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="line-item">
  <td>L2C1</td>
  <td>L2C2</td>
  <td><input class="item-text" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Mas gostaria de fazer apenas com CSS, é possível?

Comment: pode usar javascript ou é só com css?

Comment: @zwitterion css mesmo, se for possível.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues Tu consegues mudar a cor do input, mas selecionar um elemento por "logica" (ou seja, se este elemento está `focus` o PARENTE fica `red`) é complicado *sem javascript* porque o CSS e logica não andam de mãos dadas; 

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ha138wg7/) aqui está o selector para o `input` depois com javascript podes adicionar uma class `onfocus` ao parente do elemento clicado

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues editei a resposta novamente, dê uma olhada

Comment: @renan se transformar seu comentário em resposta eu já aceito, e se possível também colocar um exemplo de estrutura alternativa na qual isso funcione ficará perfeito!

Comment: Se bem que estou estudando esses exemplos para conseguir uma solução em css. [link1](http://jsfiddle.net/MQESw/3/) [link2](http://jsfiddle.net/AGgpN/3/)

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues solucionei o problema? Se sim, marque a resposta como solução, obrigado amigo

Answer (score 1):

### **Como fazer?**

Use `JS` embutido na própria class

### **Explicando**

Usando as funções `onClick`, `onMouseOver` e `onMouseOut` é possível fazer hover e focus sem usar `css`.

**Code:**

```html
<table border="1">
<tr style="cursor:default" onMouseover="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff00'" onclick="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor='#ff0000'" onMouseOut="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor=''">
  <td>L1C1</td>
  <td>L1C2</td>
  <td><input class="teste" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr style="cursor:default" onMouseover="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor='#ffff00'" onclick="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor='#ff0000'" onMouseOut="javascript:this.style.backgroundColor=''">
  <td>L2C1</td>
  <td>L2C2</td>
  <td><input class="teste2"" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Referencia: [Mouse Events](http://javascript.info/tutorial/mouse-events)

Comment: muito obrigado pela resposta, mas infelizmente ela não atende meu problema. Editei a pergunta pra que ela fique mais clara, se puder ajudar ficarei muito grato!

Comment: Editei a resposta, de uma olhada novamente @JedaiasRodrigues

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues ao passar o mouse, ela muda para amarelo e ao selecionar ela muda para vermelho, não era isso que estava querendo?

Comment: VictorGomes eu acho que o @Jedaias quer que *o parent* do input também mude de cor (aka a parte que tem LnCn)

Comment: @VictorGomes em minha pergunta eu gostaria que uma linha inteira da tabela mude de cor, ou seja, o `:focus` do `text` mudaria o `backgroud-color` de outra classe de elementos e não dele mesmo como foi colocado em sua resposta.

Comment: @JedaiasRodrigues assim ?

Comment: @VictorGomes muito obrigado mesmo pela ajuda! Mas infelizmente eu gostaria de usar apenas CSS, é possível?

Comment: Por que não usar JS @JedaiasRodrigues? Essa forma é tão simples...

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que vai ser meio difícil sem usar javascript.
Se vc quiser usar JS essa é uma possível **[solução](https://jsfiddle.net/hwr5dweo/)**.

```
//HTML
<table border="1">
<tr class="line_item">
  <td>L1C1</td>
  <td>L1C2</td>
  <td><input class="item_text" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
<tr class="line_item">
  <td>L2C1</td>
  <td>L2C2</td>
  <td><input class="item_text" type="text" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

//Js code
$('tr.line_item').on( 'mouseenter', function() {
  $( this ).css({
    'outline': '1px solid #abb3b3',
    'background-color': '#E9E900'
  });
}).on( 'mouseleave', function() {
  $( this ).removeAttr('style');
});

$('.item_text').bind({        
    keyup:function(){
    objectEvent=$(this);

    if(objectEvent.val()!==""){
      //alert(objectEvent.val());
      objectEvent.css({    
            'background-color': '#FF0000'
        });
    }
    else{
        objectEvent.removeAttr('style');
    }
  }//Fim keyUp
});
```

Nota:
Eu mudei o nome da classe de `line-item` para `line_item`. Embora não represente um problema, trata-se boas práticas de programação.
Tente apagar o texto e veja o que acontece.